# Просуммировать среднее значение сгруппированных метрик

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

Приходят какие-то метрики. Скажем `items_count`. Интервал разный каждый раз. Вывожу на графике как max/mean, группируя по хосту.

Но хочу так же на этом графике вывести сумму. Что-то вроде:

```
SELECT sum(mean("items_count")) FROM "Items" [...] GROUP BY $host
```

Но из коробки influx такое не умеет. Как можно выкрутиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, это можно сделать, используя [Continuous Queries](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/continuous_queries/). В моём случае это будет:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "eu_west_planets" ON "Unnyworld" 
BEGIN 
    SELECT max("value") as "planets" INTO "eu_west_planets" FROM "autogen"."rooms.running" WHERE ("index"='2' OR "index"='1') AND "service_type"='zone' and "region"='eu-west' and "zoneType"='PLANET'  GROUP BY time(10s),"host", "index" 
END
```

Эта штука будет с тайм семплингом в 10 секунд брать максимальное значение количества комнат игровых планет на каждом хосте, сгруппировав значения по хосту и индексу (у нас на машине запущено 2 инстанса игровых планет) и писать в `eu_west_planets`.

После чего в самом Chronograf'е я могу написать запрос:

```
SELECT sum("planets") AS "sum_planets" FROM "Unnyworld"."autogen"."eu_west_planets" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: GROUP BY time(10s)
```

Теперь в итоге я получаю сумму всех запущенных игровых комнат в европейском регионе.

**Вывод:** написать вложенные запросы в лоб нельзя, но можно подзапрос оформить как Continuous Queries и потом на нём уже какую-нибудь функцию для агрегации использовать.